# output an Array with same values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a SQL Query result (array): "title", "content" and "name"
Here is my var_dump:

```
array(28) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "Basis Task"
    ["content"]=>
    string(43) "https://www.wrike.com/open.htm?id=440908999"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Christian Wahl"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "Basis Task"
    ["content"]=>
    string(5) "MySQL"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Christian Wahl"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["content"]=>
    string(3) "PHP"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Christian Wahl"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["content"]=>
    string(3) "PHP"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Christian Wahl"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "Basis Task"
    ["content"]=>
    string(7) "content"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Elena Ott"
  }
```

(I cut off the end of the array to make it a little clearer to see)
These are Tasks who are assigned to a User.

Now i want to output the "Name" (panel-heading)
and the "title" and "content" (panel-body).

It should look smth like this but for each given name:

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIkO6.png)

I tried to find a solution on my own, but without success :( 
I hope u can help me?

thx a lot

-Taddl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just loop on your data and render it

```php
$data = [];
foreach ($databaseResult as $row) {
  $data[$row['name']][] = $row;
}
foreach($data as $name => $stuff) {
  echo $name . '<br>';
  foreach($stuff as $row) {
    echo $row["title"] . ':' . $row["content"] . '<BR>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop. As example:

```
foreach($yourarrayvariable as $data)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='heading'>".$data['name']."</td>";
    echo "<div class='content'>";
    echo "<td>".$data['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['content']."</td>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

And create your desired template look classes as per your need inside foreach.

Comment: Might wanna fix up those echo's with a class. This code will break

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Fixed it. Edited, thank you for the correction. :)